# As my blog is centric to southeast Asian audience so it’s not available in other countries. Can I continue writing blogs in F1 visa?

Tags: usa, student-visa

I have a small blog where I post marketing, branding, and online business development related articles. It’s been like 2 years now into blogging after graduation.

As the blog is concentric to mostly Southeast Asia target audience. So one can only see the site in Asia (unless using VPN). Regarding earnings the site have some useful affiliate links for readers and helps with hosting renewal cost. I am not using Adsense. Monthly earning over $1000 If lucky.

Currently I am looking forward to do an MBA in marketing from USA. So will it be legal to continue writing blogs in F1?

Answer (score 1):

Whether something is legal or not is a question to an attorney, which I believe no-one here is.

In this case it doesn't look like you're being employed and paid for the work done, and in fact you're not doing any work per se. I'd argue that this is a hobby that potentially produces some passive income (referral fees and ad revenue).

Both hobbies and passive income are allowed under F1 visa.